# SQL query to view top customers

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I am trying to make a view to see top 10 customers and this is what I have so far, what am I doing wrong?

```
CREATE VIEW vwTopCustomer
AS 
   SELECT TOP 10 * 
       (CustomerID) AS TotalMoneySpent, 
       SUM(Quantity*Price)
   FROM 
       tblCUSTOMER c
   JOIN 
       tblORDER o ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
   JOIN 
       tblORDER_PRODUCT op ON o.OrderID = op.OrderID
   JOIN 
       tblPRODUCT p ON op.ProductID = p.ProductID
   GROUP BY  
       CustomerID
   ORDER BY 
       TotalMoneySpent DESC
   GO
```

Comment: What is the Problem? Can you Show sample data? Any error?

Comment: Some sample data and expected ouput are always helpful :]

Answer (score 1):

You cant `group by` a column and then `Select *` in your query result.

Try this edited version..

```
CREATE VIEW vwTopCustomer
AS 
   SELECT TOP 10 
       (CustomerID), 
       SUM(Quantity*Price) AS TotalMoneySpent
   FROM 
       tblCUSTOMER c
   JOIN 
       tblORDER o ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
   JOIN 
       tblORDER_PRODUCT op ON o.OrderID = op.OrderID
   JOIN 
       tblPRODUCT p ON op.ProductID = p.ProductID
   GROUP BY  
       CustomerID
   ORDER BY 
       2 DESC
   GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the data, I can't be sure, but the two things I noticed is that you selected top 10 * then the two fields. Also, the second column is probably what you'll want to order by desc.

```
CREATE VIEW vwTopCustomer
AS 
   SELECT TOP 10 
       CustomerID , 
       SUM(Quantity*Price) AS TotalMoneySpent
   FROM 
       tblCUSTOMER c
   JOIN 
       tblORDER o ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
   JOIN 
       tblORDER_PRODUCT op ON o.OrderID = op.OrderID
   JOIN 
       tblPRODUCT p ON op.ProductID = p.ProductID
   GROUP BY  
       CustomerID
   ORDER BY 
       TotalMoneySpent DESC
   GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Mind you SQL Server will get `TOP 10` rows but may or may not show in the order you expect it to be shown.

This is a limitation with sql server. The returned rows will be *"Correct"* `TOP 10` but not in the order of the intended `ORDER BY` clause.

You will need to use the `ORDER BY` clause when selecting from your view.

```
CREATE VIEW vwTopCustomer
AS 
   SELECT TOP 10  CustomerID 
             ,SUM(Quantity*Price) AS TotalMoneySpent
   FROM  tblCUSTOMER c
   JOIN  tblORDER o          ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
   JOIN  tblORDER_PRODUCT op ON o.OrderID = op.OrderID
   JOIN  tblPRODUCT p        ON op.ProductID = p.ProductID
   GROUP BY   CustomerID
   ORDER BY  TotalMoneySpent DESC
GO
```

**Select from View**

```
SELECT * FROM vwTopCustomer
ORDER BY TotalMoneySpent DESC
```

**ORDER BY in Views**

> Order the result set of a query by the specified column list and,
>   optionally, limit the rows returned to a specified range. The order in
>   which rows are returned in a result set are not guaranteed unless an
>   ORDER BY clause is specified.

[`BOL Referrence`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx)